# How to use ContentResolver to save images for devices running below API 29/AndroidQ?

Tags: android

To save an image to the shared/external folders in Android Q and above we must use `ContentResolver` and save to either root folder `../Pictures` or `../DCIM` like in the following code:

```
        ContentResolver resolver = .getContentResolver();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, "myfile");
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, "myApp"); //RequiresApi 29
        Uri imageUri = resolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues);
        OutputStream out = resolver.openOutputStream(imageUri);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
```

I would like to resuse this code down to `minSDK 19` but it is not possible due to column `MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH` which Requires Api 29. Is there any smart way to do this?

Currently I support devices running below API 29 like this:

```
        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES;
        File directory = new File(path);
        directory.mkdirs()
        File file = new File(directory, filename + fileExtension);
        OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file))
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
```

Comment: `I would like to resuse this code down to minSDK 19 but it is not possible due to column MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH which Requires Api 29.` If you just do not execute that line below api 29 then what happens?

Comment: @blackapps I will try that